# Closing alert dialog with return key sends a keyup event to the focused input box, resulting in an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, alert, infinite-loop, onkeyup

The following code creates an infinite loop. When you press return to close the alert dialog (as opposed to *clicking* the "OK"), it sends the keyup event to the input box that has focus, even though the target of the return key keyup event should really be the alert dialog button. But since my input box complains with an alert when it gets a return key keyup event, it triggers the alert window again. This cycle continues until you try to close the alert dialog with the mouse.

My real code is more complicated, but this MWE exhibits the problem.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8mqmjpw2/

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="my-input-box" type="text" value="Test value">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var closureVariable = null;
        var inputBox = document.getElementById("my-input-box");
        inputBox.onkeyup = function(event) { 
            if(event.keyCode === 13) {
                console.log("this: ", this, "event.target: ", event.target);
                someOtherFunction(this, closureVariable);
            }
        };

        function someOtherFunction(inputBox, closureVariable) {
            if(!closureVariable) {
                alert("Required variable does not exist.");
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can this problem be solved? And is this a JS implementation bug?

The behavior occurs in Firefox 31.0, Safari 7.0.5 (9537.77.4), Chrome 37.0.2062.94 and Opera 24.0.1558.53. The behavior is not present on Android browser when pressing the "Go" button. Maybe someone else could test IE?

Comment: your fiddle doesnt create a problem. anyways one bad trick is to set `this.onkeyup=function(){};` (empty function) before alert and `this.onkeyup=arguments.callee;` (the same) function back after the alert

Comment: @Sunand What browser did you test the fiddle in? I tested in Safari, Firefox and Chrome - all had the same problem.

Comment: chrome 35.0.1916.153

Comment: I tested with chrome 37, so I doubt I'm experiencing the problem but you aren't. Are you actually pressing return/enter as opposed to clicking OK? It only happens when you press return repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you not using event listeners this would work

```
var closureVariable = null;
var inputBox = document.getElementById("my-input-box");
inputBox.onkeydown=function(){
    inputBox.onkeyup = function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode === 13) {
            console.log("this: ", this, "event.target: ", event.target);
            inputBox.onkeyup =function(){};
            someOtherFunction(this, closureVariable);
            //inputBox.onkeyup =function(){alert(Math.random())}
        }
    };
};

function someOtherFunction(inputBox, closureVariable) {
    if(!closureVariable) {
        alert("Required variable does not exist.");
    }
 }
```

Comment: Very clever, thanks. I want to find out if this is actually a bug, but until then this solution will work.

Answer (score 0):

If using jQuery I would

```
event.preventDefault();
return false();
```

on `focus` event